# ¿Cuál es el equivalente a jsrsasign-all-min.js en C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

tengo la siguiente tarea por realizar: me envían documentación de que debo encriptar y firmar un archivo PKCS8, me dan el ejemplo en javascript con una librería que hasta hace unos días conocí, logré hacerlo funcionar aunque no entiendo bien como lo hace. la cuestión es que debo hacerla en el servidor para realizar multiples solicitudes con un foreach.

Ya llevo tiempo dando vueltas con esto y en un lado dicen que con RSA nativo de C# que es con Bouncy Castle, probé con [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830510/c-sharp-sign-data-with-rsa-using-bouncycastle/8845111) pero ni idea de cual es el módulo y cual es el exponente entonces cual es el equivalente de esto o es que no existe?

este es el código de ejemplo:

```js
// Esta funcion convierte de hexadecimal a base 64
function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
      str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" "))
    );
}


// Esto es para cargar la libreria que permite hacer el firmado SHA1withRSA
var navigator = {}; 
var window = {}; 
eval(postman.getGlobalVariable("jsrsasign-js"));

// Leer la llave privada previamente se debe cargar en la variable global llavepem 
// con la llave en formato pkcs8
var key = KEYUTIL.getKey(postman.getGlobalVariable("llavepem"));

// Indicar el algoritmo
var sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA1withRSA"});

// Indicar la llave para la firma
sig.init(key);

console.log(request.data.replace("{{usuarioWeb}}",pm.globals.get("usuarioWeb")));
// Tomar el cuerpo del mensaje
sig.updateString(request.data.replace("{{usuarioWeb}}", pm.globals.get("usuarioWeb")).replace("{{llavehmac}}",pm.globals.get("llavehmac")));

// Realizar el firmado, este retorna un string en base hexadecimal
var hSigVal = sig.sign();

// Tomar los bytes de hexadecimal y convertirlo a base 64
var base64 = hexToBase64(hSigVal);

// Se adiciona la variable al encabezado
pm.variables.set('firma', base64);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jsrsasign`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsrsasign) es una librería criptográfica que usa demasiados tipos de cifrado, y encontrar un equivalente sería básicamente imposible, pero, lo que sí puedes encontrar son clases que realicen funciones específicas de acuerdo a cada uno de los cripto-módulos de `jsrsasign`.

Por ejemplo, para realizar un cifrado RSA usando el modo `CBC`, un [`Padding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=netframework-4.8) `PKCS7`, tendrías lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

---

```
private static byte[] myKey = "UiX8kOpGQ8994ar1/cNqzV8sRN67uqD8L/Q75Yaev6s=";

public static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText)
{
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    byte[] encrypted;

    using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
    {

        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
        aesAlg.Key = myKey.Take(16).ToArray();
        aesAlg.IV =  myKey.Skip(16).ToArray();

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

Donde:

```
aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;            --> Modo de cifrado
aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;      --> Padding deseado
aesAlg.KeySize = 128;                    --> Tamaño de la llave en bits
aesAlg.Key = myKey.Take(16).ToArray();   --> Llave de 16 bytes requerida para un cifrado a 128 bits 
aesAlg.IV =  myKey.Skip(16).ToArray();   --> Vector de inicialización de 16 bytes
```

---

Para el método de descifrado, deberás usar las mismas opciones, sino, no obtendrás el resultado esperado.

```
public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText)
{
    if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");

    byte[] plainText = null;
    string plaintext = null;
    using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
    {
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
        aesAlg.Key = myKey.Take(16).ToArray();
        aesAlg.IV =  myKey.Skip(16).ToArray();

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
            }
            plainText = ms.ToArray();
        }
        plaintext = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Phi, voy a probar con este método haber como me va.

Comment: @Vulpex si te interesa el método para descifrar el texto cifrado también la hice

Comment: Gracias @Phi, pues de momento no parece que lo necesitara, pero no está de más tenerlo, si me lo puedes copiar te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: @Vulpex servido *mister* ;)